# The Parallel GC can not be combined with -XX:ParallelGCThreads=0

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtual Box and I installed Oracle Java 8 (not openJDK).

When I try to run a java program I get the error

> The Parallel GC can not be combined with -XX:ParallelGCThreads=0

This seems to be a java issue, what are my options to resolve this?

Comment: It's possible to set (basically) command line options from within a Jar file.  My guess is the person who made the Jar put some bad options in it.  You may need to 1. Contact the vendor and ask for a correct Jar, or 2. Hack it yourself.  If you are the one supplying the command line arguments, then just leave off the `-XX` option in your title.

Comment: Think about what you're asking for here.  You want a garbage collector that runs on a background thread, but explicitly told it to use 0 threads.

Comment: *"what are my options to resolve this?"* Specify a value other than 0, or don't use Parallel GC. The error message seems pretty clear and *logical*, so if those two cannot be specified together, don't, i.e. change one of them. I don't understand which part of that isn't obvious.

Comment: @Andreas This is not a program I developed so I did not want to go poking around with out some outside opinions first.